# Use INSERT SELECT and UPDATE all in 1 query. Is that right?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Using mySQL I am trying to add values from table1 into table 2 BUT also add in some static values for each record like "$username", 'NOW(), and 'text'.

The code I have at the moment is

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO table2 (auto_id, id, field_1, field_2)
SELECT 'null', ID, field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE ID = '{$_GET['delcarer']}' 
UPDATE table2 SET field_3 = NOW(), field_4 = '$username', field_5 = 'text'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
```

Is that at all right?! BTW total noob here as I am sure you will be able to tell from my other posts!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you've got two queries in one run (which won't work).
The first inserts a row into table2 based on info from table1.
The second updates all rows in table2.

If that's what you want, just run the two one by one.

If you only want to alter the lines you just added to table2, this might be what you're looking for:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table2 (auto_id, id, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field5)
SELECT 'null', ID, field1, field2, NOW(), '$username', 'text' FROM table1 WHERE ID = '{$_GET['delcarer']}';
```

By the way:
Beware SQL injection leaks. Someone could put half a query in your GET delcarer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I thought of doing it that way but I thought it would try to select the '$username' and 'text' from the table.  Or am I confusing the issue.

Comment: You need to keep track of what gets executed by what. $var = " $some "; will get picked up by PHP. 2 more things: 1: Btw this isn't the best way to build up a query. Check out sprintf and prepared statements to prevent creating sql injection leaks. 2: 'null' is different from NULL. NULL is a magic value that means "nope, no value here" while 'null' is a 4 letter string.